# How Can I debug a asp net core RC2 solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How Can I debug a asp net core RC2 solution? I run it based only all framework( net451). where Can I find the latest Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools for visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

As RC2 is not officially released by now, and there is no release date set yet (see [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)), your are stuck with RC1 right now, if you need documentation (see [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/)).

More Information on RC2 developement : [can be found here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnUpdateOnASPNETCore10RC2.aspx) .